# Keeping GUI and logic loosely coupled in Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

Original post:

[Tic Tac Toe game with emphasis on design and readability](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/77993/tic-tac-toe-game-with-emphasis-on-design-and-readability)

I got great help, but I feel like I have to ask how I can keep the GUI and logic loosely coupled. Is there any best practice that I should follow?

I tried to pass `MainFrame` object to `Games` constructor instead, but then I had to redesign `MainFrame` cause it's tightly coupled to `Game`, but `MainFrame` needs to call the `Logic` in `Game`. Any tips on how to redesign this will be greatly appreciated.

**TicTacToe.java**

```
package tictactoe;

public class TicTacToe {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Game g = new Game();   
    }

}
```

**Game.java**

```
package tictactoe;

import tictactoe.GameBoard.Board;
import tictactoe.GameGui.MainFrame;
import tictactoe.GamePlayer.Player;
import tictactoe.GamePlayer.PlayerType;

public class Game {

    private final Board board = new Board();
    private final Player crossPlayer = new Player(board, PlayerType.Cross);
    private final Player circlePlayer = new Player(board, PlayerType.Circle);
    private Player currentPlayer = crossPlayer;
    private MainFrame frame;

    public Game() {
        frame = new MainFrame(this);
    }
    public void togglePlayer() {
        if (currentPlayer.equals(crossPlayer)) {
            currentPlayer = circlePlayer;
        } else {
            currentPlayer = crossPlayer;
        }
    }
    /*
        Called when the player clicks on the ith square.
    */
    public void makeMove(int i) {
        //find what row and col, the i:th square lies on.
        int row = i/3;
        int col = i%3;

        currentPlayer.makeMove(row, col);
        frame.markSquare(i, currentPlayer);
        frame.disableSquare(i);
        togglePlayer();
        display();
    }

    /**
     * Display the board in the console, used for debbuging purposes
     */
    public void display() {
        PlayerType markType;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                markType = board.getSquare(i, j).getMark();
                System.out.print(markType.toString());
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

   private PlayerType getMark(int i, int j)  //rename 
   {
       return board.getSquare(i, j).getMark();
   }
    public PlayerType checkDiag() {

        if (getMark(0,0) == getMark(1,1) && getMark(0,0) == getMark(2,2)) {
            return getMark(0,0);
        }
        if (getMark(0,2) == getMark(1,1) && getMark(0,2) == getMark(2,0)) {
            return getMark(0,2);
        }
        return PlayerType.None;
    }

    public PlayerType checkCol(int col) {
        if (getMark(0, col) == getMark(1, col) && getMark(0,col) == getMark(2, col)){
            return getMark(0,col);
        }
        return PlayerType.None;
    }

    public PlayerType checkRow(int row) {

        if (getMark(row, 0) == getMark(row, 1) && getMark(row, 0) == getMark(row, 2)) { //row full
            return getMark(row, 0);
        }

        return PlayerType.None;
    }

    public PlayerType playerWon() {
        PlayerType winner;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            winner = checkRow(i);
            if (winner != PlayerType.None) {
                return winner;
            }

            winner = checkCol(i);
            if (winner != PlayerType.None) {
                return winner;
            }
        }
        return checkDiag();
    }

}
```

**PlayerType.java**

```
package tictactoe.GamePlayer;

public enum PlayerType {
    None("*"),
    Cross("X"),
    Circle("O");

    private final String symbol;

    PlayerType(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

**MainFrame.java**

```
package tictactoe.GameGui;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import tictactoe.Game;
import tictactoe.GamePlayer.Player;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private final List<JButton> squares = new ArrayList<>();         //Squares that the player can mark X or O.
    private JPanel SquaresPanel = new JPanel(); //The panel that holds the squares on the window.
    private Game game;

    private final int WinHeight = 300;
    private final int WinWidth = 300;
    private final int nrOffSquares = 9;

    public MainFrame(Game game) {
        super("Tic Tac Toe");
        this.game = game;

        initWindow();
        initSquares();  
        initSquaresPanel();

    }
    private void initWindow() {

        setSize(WinWidth, WinHeight);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initSquares() {

        for (int i = 0; i < nrOffSquares; i++) {
            JButton b = new JButton();
            b.setFont(b.getFont().deriveFont(18.0f));
            b.addActionListener(this);
            SquaresPanel.add(b);
            squares.add(b);
        }
    }

    private void initSquaresPanel() {

        SquaresPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3)); 
        add(SquaresPanel);
    }

    public void markSquare(int i, Player p) {
        squares.get(i).setText(p.getType().toString());
    }
    public void disableAllSquares() {
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOffSquares; i++)
            disableSquare(i);
    }
    public void disableSquare(int i) {
        squares.get(i).setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();

        for (int i = 0; i < nrOffSquares; i++) {
            if (b.equals(squares.get(i))) {        //if the ith square is clicked
                game.makeMove(i);                  //Make a move on the ith square.
            }
        } 
    }

}
```

**Player.java**

```
package tictactoe.GamePlayer;

import tictactoe.GameBoard.Board;

public class Player {

    private PlayerType type;
    private Board board;

    public Player(Board board, PlayerType type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.board = board;
    }
    public void makeMove(int row, int col) {
        board.setSquare(row, col, type);
    }
    public PlayerType getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

**Board.java**

```
package tictactoe.GameBoard;

import tictactoe.GamePlayer.PlayerType;

public class Board {
    private Square  board[][] = new Square [3][3];
    public Board() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                board[i][j] = new Square();
            }
        }
    }
    public void setSquare (int row, int col, PlayerType type) {
        board[row][col].setMark(type);
    }
    public Square getSquare(int row, int col) {
        return board[row][col];
    }
}
```

**Square.java**

```
package tictactoe.GameBoard;

import tictactoe.GamePlayer.PlayerType;

public class Square {
    private PlayerType mark = PlayerType.None;

    public PlayerType getMark() {
        return mark;
    }

    public void setMark(PlayerType mark) {
        this.mark = mark;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will purely focus on coupling between different classes here, since that is what you asked for:

- The `Game` class can work without the coupling to `MainFrame`. I think the purpose of `Game` should be the logic of the game and for this logic no knowledge of the GUI is required. Something like requesting an array with the board layout could be useful for testing and debugging (and even GUI) purposes.
- The `MainFrame` has two responsibilities: Showing the game board and performing the actions. By refactoring the `MainFrame` to a Model-View-Controller mechanism, you will get fewer responsibilities and it can make the code easier to read. The Model will be the `Game` class, the View the part of `MainFrame` that shows the board and the controller is the place where you make your move. Here you can get the logic for disabling squares and calling the methods on Game.

Comment: Thanks i have now looked into MVC, my new approach is to have a class Controller(frame, game) (rename when suitable name  found) and implement the ActionListener there, i liked this aproach much better. i read about the model as an Observable made me a little confused, so maybe for another project. There is still alot to redesign, but now i think i getting closer to good design.

Comment: The Observable part of the model is something that is used a lot in MVC, so perhaps the MVP (Model View Presenter) is a better option (basically MVC without the Observable part...)

Answer (score 2):

At a quick glance at the code

- Your `Game` class would strongly benefit from changing single letter variable names to more meaningful ones.

  ```
  public void makeMove(int squareNumber) {

      int row = squareNumber / 3;
      int col = squareNumber % 3;

      currentPlayer.makeMove(row, col);
      frame.markSquare(squareNumber, currentPlayer);
      frame.disableSquare(squareNumber);
      togglePlayer();
      display();
  }
  ```
- giving your variables some space to breathe will improve the readability.

  > ```
  > int row = i/3;
  > ```

  should be

  ```
   int row = i / 3;
  ```
- you should name your variables using `camelCase` casing, or at least be consistent with the casing you use.

  > ```
  > private Game game;
  >
  > private final int WinHeight = 300;
  > private final int WinWidth = 300;
  > private final int nrOffSquares = 9;
  > ```
- using braces `{}` for single statement `loop` will make your code less errorprone

  > ```
  > public void disableAllSquares() {
  >    for (int i = 0; i < nrOffSquares; i++)
  >        disableSquare(i);
  > }
  > ```

  would be "safer" like

  ```
  public void disableAllSquares() {
      for (int i = 0; i < nrOffSquares; i++) {
          disableSquare(i);
      }
  }
  ```
- comments should describe **why** something is done. **What** is done should be described by the code itself by using meaningful names for methods, classes and variables.